# Outlook Query Builder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to add multiple conditions  in the query builder but failing to get both conditions to work ,  only the first 2 rules apply  the third rule after the OR  is not working

I have them setup as follows , any idea what is wrong ?

﻿[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI5HT.png)

Comment: I think these criteria are incorrectly. If I set similar criteria as yours, I got same results with yours. Would you describe your requirement in detail so I may help adjust your settings?

Comment: thanks Perry i want the search folder to catch emails that match                                                                                   = condition 1 and (( condition 2 and condition 3) or (condition 4 and condition 5 and condition 6))  ..          so o need all emails with a combination of condition 1 ,2 and 3 ,  and also all emails with a combination condition 1,4,5,6                i hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic has some problems. If you find out the category is A, why you want to add condition 1 (doesn’t contain). You can check this

[image]

Comment: This worked Perry !   thankyou very much for your help :)

Comment: how do i flag your comment as the answer ?

Comment: @MohamedMaghrabi you can click "accept" :)